# how to hide li with slide effect in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `ul` and on click of one of its `li` I want to hide sub `ul` in it with sliding effect. I have tried `animation` with `height` from 100% to 0. But this is not working.

This is code snippet and in real scenario there will be dynamic data and n no of `li`

```js
function hide() {
  var li = document.getElementById("game");
  game.classList.add("hide")
}
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 75%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li onclick="hide()">b</li>
  <li id="game" style="height:100%">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Fix the height 100% issue and your animation will work

Comment: you can use the css `transition` for doing that.

Comment: can you please give the code snippet

Comment: @SunilGarg have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vikscool/q5qquavf/) i am playing with the width and for more info you can look at [W3School Transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using percentages will not work in your example.

*Solution 1*: You need to set a fixed height in the `@keyframes` like so:

```js
function hide() {
  var li = document.getElementById("game");
  game.classList.add("hide")
}
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  25% {
    height: 30px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li onclick="hide()">b</li>
  <li id="game">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

*Solution 2:* Add a fixed height to the parent `<ul>` element and then you can use percentages in your `@keyframe`s like so:

```js
function hide() {
  var li = document.getElementById("game");
  game.classList.add("hide")
}
```

```css
.hide {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

ul {
  height: 200px;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
  }
  25% {
    height: 75%;
  }
  50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li onclick="hide()">b</li>
  <li id="game">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

[Here is an article](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/) that goes into detail on this subject.

Comment: this works but in real scenario data is binding dynamically so there could be n no if li, so how can I identify what px i should start from ?

Comment: @SunilGarg Ah, that's a good point. You should edit your question to include that this data is dynamic. In that case, if you give the parent `<ul>` element a fixed height then you can use percentages. The reason percentages aren't working in your example is because there is no element with a fixed height so when you add a percentage, the renderer is like "50% of what?! Nothing has a fixed height so I'm supposed to render this element 50% height of what?!" I added a solution where you can use percentages if you set a fixed height on the parent. You can also look into using `vh` units.

Comment: Can't I give height in %, because I dont know the no of li so I dont know intial height in px? and I have updated the question

Comment: @SunilGarg I updated my answer. You will need a fixed height somewhere, so perhaps you could set the height of the `<ul>` to a hard-coded value of `vh` units if it needs to be responsive. If this helped, please mark my answer as accepted. Thank you and best of luck.

Comment: @SunilGarg Ultimately you may have to use JavaScript to dynamically adjust the height of the `<ul>` element. For example, if there are `x` number of `<li>` elements and you know you need `20px` for each of them, then you can use JavaScript to set the height of the `<ul>` to `x * 20px`.